# (MySQL) SET column with values from a foreign key constrant

Tags: mysql

I am making a junction table that tracks relationships between users. Among other things it is formatted with a group leader, and with a variable amount of members. All users have a user id and so this relationship between leader and members must constrain to the defined uuids in the users table.

Currently, the only way I know how to accomplish this is to make a bunch of columns named `member1`, `member2` and so on, and then make foreign key constraints on each column, but this is inefficient as the number of members in a group varies from entry to entry. So I thought to use a SET type for the members column. **However, the SET column type forces you to define constants for it, and this simply isn't possible with a wide amount of user ids.**

So in essence, my question is, how can I make a set whose values are constrained to the values in another table? I'm trying my best to follow the standard practice of using junction tables, but if you have a better organizational solution which allows me to sidestep this issue entirely while still accomplishing the same or similar goal that would also be most appreciated.

Edit: Group id is synonymous with leader id because groups are identified by their leaders.

Comment: Var.1: Separate relation table `junction (leader_id, member_id)` where each separate field referrences to `users` table independently. Var2. `groups` table with `leader_id` field referenced to `users`. Relational table `junction (group_id, member_id)` where `group_id` is referenced to `groups` and `member_id` is referenced to `users`.

Comment: Hi @Akina, I don't quite understand your comment. Are you saying to make a third table? Also, the group id is synonymous with the leader id. I forgot to mention that, but I'll edit my question now.

Comment: *the group id is synonymous with the leader id.* If so use variant 1. *Are you saying to make a third table?* Of course - "group" is separate entity. But why third? `user` + `group`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schematically.

```
CREATE TABLE users ( id PRIMARY KEY, ... );
CREATE TABLE groups ( leader_id REFERENCES users (id),
                      member_id REFERENCES users (id) );
```

The keys (including primary) and constraints in `groups` are dependent by:

- does the user may be a member of one group only, or of a lot of groups;
- does the group leader may be a member of another group (rings possible);
- does a leader must (or may) be a member of his own group.

Comment: I think you don't quite understand the question. The way you have the groups table makes it so only a single member_id may be in each entry. I need a set of member-id in each entry of the groups table.

Comment: @hjk321 *only a single member_id may be in each entry* ??? Of course! One member - one record. Ten members - ten records with the same `leader_id`. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

> a group leader, and with a variable amount of members

That sounds like a 1:many mapping.  Such is implemented by having a column `leader_id` (with FK) in the `members` table.